# send signature using curl mixmax api key

Tags: php, curl

can anybody please tell me how to send email signature text using curl with mixmax,

mixmax email send functionality already working.

```
$data = array('message' => array('to' => $toEmail, 'from' => 'email_id', "subject" => $subject, "html" => $content));
    $data_string = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.mixmax.com/v1/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'X-API-Token: API key here',
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: so what problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: actually i want to send signatures with my email in bottom of my email message for every email from back end.